# How to keep user logged in when using FB plugin to sign in?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to find out how to keep user logged in. I am using Facebook Plugin and storing the user data in CosmosDB, however i am not sure what data do i need to keep the user logged in or when to actually ask his permission as i am redirected straight to Facebook login.

This is the code that i am using to sign in

```
 async Task LoginFacebookAsync(User user)
        {
            try
            {

                if (_facebookService.IsLoggedIn)
                {
                    _facebookService.Logout();
                }

                EventHandler<FBEventArgs<string>> userDataDelegate = null;

                userDataDelegate = async (object sender, FBEventArgs<string> e) =>
                {
                    if (e == null) return;

                    switch (e.Status)
                    {
                        case FacebookActionStatus.Completed:
                            var facebookProfile = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookProfile>(e.Data));
                           var socialLoginData = new User
                            {
                                UserEmail = facebookProfile.Email,
                                UserName = $"{facebookProfile.FirstName} {facebookProfile.LastName}",
                                Id = facebookProfile.UserId,

                            };
                            
                            user.UserEmail = socialLoginData.UserEmail;
                            user.UserName = socialLoginData.UserName;
                            user.Id = socialLoginData.Id;
                         

                            user = await UserViewModel.GetOrCreateUser(user);
                            UserViewModel.SetUser(user);


                            await App.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
                            App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
                            break;
                        case FacebookActionStatus.Canceled:
                            break;
                    }

                    _facebookService.OnUserData -= userDataDelegate;
                };

                _facebookService.OnUserData += userDataDelegate;

                string[] fbRequestFields = { "email", "first_name", "gender", "last_name" };
                string[] fbPermisions = { "email" };
                await _facebookService.RequestUserDataAsync(fbRequestFields, fbPermisions);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Please if you could help how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use local db like Sqlite or Settings Plugin to save the authentication token, expire date etc. So when the app run you can check them and let the user automatically login or not.